# How to join max/min date column on select with last date where data on it

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have to join one table with 2 parameters to show last update status of detail to check finish/ongoing with MAX(...)/MIN(...). What can i do for this?

I have tried LEFT JOIN but it return to null

```
SELECT a.showonly 
     , a.want_this_parameter_lastdate
     , min(a.xdate) start
     , max(a.xdate) stop
     , b.lastdate
  FROM samedatabase a
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT xdate lastdate
                       , want_this_parameter_lastdate 
                    FROM samedatabase 
                   WHERE ROWNUM = 1 
                  ORDER BY xdate DESC) b
              ON a.want_this_parameter_lastdate = b.want_this_parameter_lastdate
 WHERE something IN (SELECT DISTINCT equalsomething 
                       FROM another WHERE input like '...') 
   AND xdate> sysdate - 7
GROUP BY a.showonly, a.want_this_parameter_lastdate, b.lastdate
ORDER BY start ASC;
```

after I query I get this

```
showonly|want_this_parameter|start  |stop   |lastdate
a1      |b1*                |5/7/19 |6/7/19 |(null)
a2      |b2**               |6/7/19 |7/7/19 |(null)
a3      |b1*                |7/7/19 |8/7/19 |(null)
a4      |b2**               |9/7/19 |10/7/19|(null)
a5      |b4                 |10/7/19|11/7/19|(null)
```

I have expect this (***stop*** is last b1 used in a1 , ***lastdate*** is last b1 used in all table)

```
showonly|want_this_parameter|start  |stop   |lastdate
a1      |b1*                |5/7/19 |6/7/19 |12/17/19--Last B1 used
a2      |b2**               |6/7/19 |7/7/19 |11/17/19--Last B2 used
a3      |b1*                |7/7/19 |8/7/19 |12/17/19--Last B1 used
a4      |b2**               |9/7/19 |10/7/19|12/17/19--Last B2 used
a5      |b4                 |10/7/19|11/7/19|12/17/19--Last B4 used

*Same b1
**Same b2
```

**UPDATE**
I finally get this but still concern about time to query performance
because MAX(...) will fetch entire table right?
How can I improve this performance.

```sql
SELECT a.showonly
     , a.want_this_parameter_lastdate
     , min(a.xdate) start
     , max(a.xdate) stop
     , b.lastdate
  FROM samedatabase a 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(xdate) lastdate, want_this_parameter_lastdate 
                    FROM samedatabase 
                  GROUP BY want_this_parameter_lastdate) b
              ON a.want_this_parameter_lastdate = b.want_this_parameter_lastdate
 WHERE something IN (SELECT DISTINCT equalsomething 
                       FROM another 
                      WHERE input like '...') 
   AND xdate> sysdate - 7
GROUP BY a.showonly, a.want_this_parameter_lastdate, b.lastdate
ORDER BY start ASC;
```

Comment: Without the sample rows from your table, it is hard to know what you're expecting. Show us some of the sample rows in your table for which you are expecting this result.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I have adding more sample row and description. Thank for advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that simple subquery would make the job faster, this way you eliminate double grouping, which is not neccesary:

```
select showonly, parameter, min(xdate) min_dt, max(xdate) max_dt,
       (select max(xdate) from samedatabase where parameter = s1.parameter) lst_dt
  from samedatabase s1
  where xdate > sysdate - 7
    and something in (select equalsomething from another where input like 'i%')
  group by showonly, parameter
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=62964ff9bf819fa55f4e303eaacb6bcf)</sup>**